# Can a variable change value during single function call (from the outside?)

Tags: javascript

I have been meaning to read the entire ECMA5-6 spec, *cough*, but maybe y'all can help me instead!

Can a variable be changed from "the outside" over the course of execution of a single call in JavaScript?

Pseudo-javascript example:

```
window.foo = true;

startSomeLoopMutatingFoo();

function f() { 
   var a = window.foo;

   // Insert long, blocking work here, none of which mutates window.foo

   var b = window.foo; // again

   if (a != b) { totalMindExplosion() }
}
```

Will my mind be blown? Could totalMindExplosion() be called under any conceivable circumstance?

Here's a JS fiddle to facilitate mind fracking: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf3rc/

I'm looking for resources to learn about when asynchronous methods are executed, direct answers, or questions of clarity.

Thanks SO!

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. While `f` runs, no other code is executed (unless of course called by `f`). Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2734025/218196

Comment: you said blocking work which means if something in that 'work' decides to assign some value then yes value would be different. As it was changed. There was no variable inside function's scope so only var was global and that was changed.

Comment: Updated to remove that case. You are 100% correct but that's not what I was after.

Comment: it depends on what window.foo is: if it's a getter for performance.now(), then yeah, it can change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, totalMindExplosion() will NOT be called.

When executed, code in a closure (function) blocks the process, there is no chance to execute other code.

Example:

```
function(){
    var a = 1;
    window.setTimeOut(function(){console.log(a);}, 0);
    a = 2;
}()
```

This will log 2 instead of 1, even the timeout is 0 second. The console.log function is called only after the full function is executed, by that time, variable 'a' has been set to 2.

Comment: You should not redeclare `a`

Comment: Can you edit to make it clearer that your first sentence is your direct answer to my Q? I might then mark it correct here. Right now the bulk of your answer does not address my needs.

Comment: Done making it the answer more obvious. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From the link in the timely comment above, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

> "Run-to-completion"
>
> Each message is processed completely before any other message is
>   processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your
>   program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot
>   be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and
>   can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for
>   instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it can be stopped at
>   any point to run some other code in another thread.

So this means my mind will never be blown!